# Unable to write/read value to/from registered shared object with multiprocessing BaseManager server across multiple processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

So I have been having some troubles with the `multiprocessing` module, and namely with the [BaseManager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager).

To reproduce the issue, the following four files can be written:

1. The first file `queue_manager.py` just defines my BaseManager to be served, along with a convenience function to connect to the server.

```py
# queue_manager.py

import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 50000
PASSWORD = "password"

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def connect_to_manager(names):
    for name in names:
        QueueManager.register(name + "_input_tasks")

    manager = QueueManager(address=(ADDRESS, PORT), authkey=PASSWORD.encode('utf-8'))
    manager.connect()
    return multiprocessing.Manager().dict({name: getattr(manager, name + "_input_tasks")() for name in names})
```

2. The server logic itself with file `server.py`. Here, we want to be able to serve two queues, named 'foo' and 'bar', which we could obtain across processes by calling the `connect_to_manager()` function defined before.

```py
# server.py

from queue_manager import QueueManager, ADDRESS, PORT, PASSWORD
import queue


class Server:

    @staticmethod
    def serve(names):
        print("Serving...")
        for name in names:
            QueueManager.register(name + "_input_tasks", callable=lambda: queue.Queue())

        m = QueueManager(address=(ADDRESS, PORT), authkey=PASSWORD.encode('utf-8'))
        s = m.get_server()
        s.serve_forever()


def main(names):
    Server.serve(names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(['foo', 'bar'])
```

3. The third file `workers.py` would be composed of the multiprocessing processes that should do some tasks on these queues. Here, we only obtain the value in the queue and print it.

```py
# workers.py

import multiprocessing
from queue_manager import connect_to_manager, PASSWORD
import time

class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, input_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.input_queue = input_queue

    def run(self):
        multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = PASSWORD.encode('utf-8')
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Running...")
            if input_queue.empty():
                print("Empty")
            else:
                x = input_queue.get()
                print(x) 

def create_workers(input_queue, n_workers):
    p = MyProcess(input_queue)
    p.start()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = PASSWORD.encode('utf-8')
    name_queue_mapping = connect_to_manager(['foo', 'bar'])
    
    # assume we focus on foo queue
    input_queue = name_queue_mapping['foo']
    create_workers(input_queue, 1)
```

4. Lastly, we create a client which places some values inside the queue with `client.py`

```py
# client.py

from queue_manager import connect_to_manager, PASSWORD
import multiprocessing
import time

def client():
    multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = PASSWORD.encode('utf-8')
    names = ['foo', 'bar']
    name_queue_mapping = connect_to_manager(names)
    foo_queue = name_queue_mapping["foo"]
    bar_queue = name_queue_mapping["bar"]


    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        foo_queue.put(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client()
```

Let's say we run each of the last three files simultaneously in separate terminals (and in this order):

- `python server.py`
- `python client.py`
- `python workers.py`

The issue is that the client successfully places values in the `foo` queue. HOWEVER, they are not picked up by the `workers`.

Now one way to circumvent this is NOT to pass a lambda function to the `QueueManager.register()` call in the `serve()` function. I.e. like this:

```py
QueueManager.register(name + "_input_tasks", callable=get_foo_queue)

# where get_foo_queue is defined globally in the server.py file as such
```

```py
# server.py
my_foo_queue = queue.Queue()

def get_foo_queue():
    return my_foo_queue

class Server:
    ....
```

instead of:

```py
QueueManager.register(name + "_input_tasks", callable=lambda: queue.Queue())
```

However, I don't want to do this because I want to be able to dynamically create the queues/functions, since I don't know their names nor how many I want before I run.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in file *workers.py* method `run`, where you have references to variable `input_queue`, this needs to be changed to `self.input_queue` (see last listing).

I would then modify file file *server.py* to ensure that for a given queue name (such as *foo*, for example), that the `QueueManager` always serves up the same, ***singleton*** `queue.Queue` instance. Once you do that as follows in this updated *server.py* file ...

**Updated server.py**

```py
# server.py

from queue_manager import QueueManager, ADDRESS, PORT, PASSWORD
import queue

queues = {}

def get_queue(queue_name):
    def f():
        return queues[queue_name]
    return f

class Server:

    @staticmethod
    def serve(names):
        print("Serving...")
        for name in names:
            queue_name = name + "_input_tasks"
            q = queue.Queue()
            queues[queue_name] = q
            callable = get_queue(queue_name)
            QueueManager.register(queue_name, callable)

        m = QueueManager(address=(ADDRESS, PORT), authkey=PASSWORD.encode('utf-8'))
        s = m.get_server()
        s.serve_forever()


def main(names):
    Server.serve(names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(['foo', 'bar'])
```

... then the updated *queue_manager.py* file becomes simplified as:

**Updated queue_manager.py**

```py
# queue_manager.py

import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 50000
PASSWORD = "password"

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def connect_to_manager(names):
    for name in names:
        QueueManager.register(name + "_input_tasks")

    manager = QueueManager(address=(ADDRESS, PORT), authkey=PASSWORD.encode('utf-8'))
    manager.connect()
    return {name: getattr(manager, name + "_input_tasks")() for name in names}
```

And for good measure, the corrected *workers.py*:

**Corrected workers.py**

```py
# workers.py

import multiprocessing
from queue_manager import connect_to_manager, PASSWORD
import time

class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, input_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.input_queue = input_queue

    def run(self):
        multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = PASSWORD.encode('utf-8')
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Running...")
            if self.input_queue.empty():
                print("Empty")
            else:
                x = self.input_queue.get()
                print(x)

def create_workers(input_queue, n_workers):
    p = MyProcess(input_queue)
    p.start()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = PASSWORD.encode('utf-8')
    name_queue_mapping = connect_to_manager(['foo', 'bar'])

    # assume we focus on foo queue
    input_queue = name_queue_mapping['foo']
    create_workers(input_queue, 1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. The main workaround was to define a function which returns the callable needed. Thank you lots!

Comment: Then would you *accept* the answer?